# Pass DTS Variable to SSIS 2008 Package w/ DTEXEC

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I want to send a package variable from a stored procedure in SSMS 2008 to an SSIS package. Then pack that into an XML file.

I can send the package variables fine. I can insert into the XML file. I cannot send the variables to the XML file.

Execute SQL Task (**Doesn't Work**)

```
DECLARE @test AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'this'
SET @test = ?

SELECT
    [BATCH_TYPE_ID] as [MessageID]
 , @test            as [Type]       
 , '10189209'       as [Order]
FROM mydb

FOR XML PATH ('PALLETS'), ROOT('INT_440')
```

The 'FOR XML PATH' returns the query as an XML file. The 'SET @test = ?' I saw on a tutorial for passing DTS variables to a package.

The configuration for the SQL Task Editor is below.

[image: SQL Task Editor]

When I run it:

```
Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "DECLARE @test AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'this'
SET @test =..." failed with the following error: "Parameter names cannot be a mixture of ordinal and named types.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

**How do I use the variables below?**
[image: Parameter Mapping]

The result is stored in a user variable and used in a Script Task below:

XML Script Task (Works)

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.InnerXml = Dts.Variables["User::XML_OUT"].Value.ToString();
xd.Save(Dts.Variables["User::XML_File"].Value.ToString());
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Querying it from SSMS(Works):

```
DECLARE @XML_FILE AS NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @SQL_QUERY AS NVARCHAR(1000) 
DECLARE @Test AS NVARCHAR(250)

SET @XML_FILE = '\Package.Variables[User::XML_File].Properties[Value];"C:\a.xml"'
SET @Test = ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::Test].Properties[Value];"BHKJASVDCJHVS"'
SET @SQL_QUERY = 'dtexec /sq INT_440 /ser myServer /SET '  + @XML_FILE + @Test

EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQL_QUERY
```

Comment: That looks like a really old version of SSIS. Are you using an unsupported version of SSIS? This would be far easier with SSISDB and Package Parameters.

Comment: Yeah I know but the SSIS catalog isn't available in SSIS 2008, that's why I have to do it this way.

Comment: Why I asked if you're using an unsupported version of SSIS, @Jack . I would suggest adding that to your question, as it is **assumed** that users are using supported software, unless they state otherwise.

Comment: I just checked and its support ended in September. I didn't know this. I changed the question title to clarify.

Comment: Yes SQL Server 2008 (and 2008R2) are now *completely* unsupported. Updating to a supported version should be a priority.

Comment: I've already asked to upgrade but its out of my control unfortunately.

Comment: @Jack , please check the solution what I have given and just let me know if you are still facing any issue , if your issue is resolve then please up vote for me and tick it as a right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code in `SQL Statement` and follow the snapshot for the solution.

```
DECLARE @test AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @test = ?
SELECT [BATCH_TYPE_ID] AS [MessageID]
    ,@test AS [Type]
    ,'10189209' AS [Order]
FROM mydb
FOR XML PATH('PALLETS') ,ROOT('INT_440')
```

- Select `REsultSet=Full result set`
- Remove `User::XML_File` from Parameter Mapping and Set `parameter Name= 0` at the place of @test.
- Go to result set table and select `USER::XML_File` as variable which you will assign in script task.

Please check the snap as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help Ajeet. This is what I got back when running it.          ``` Error: 0xC001F009 at INT_440: The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::XML_File" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.```

Comment: Seems like its somethimg to do with the string size:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437284/ssis-file-system-task-error-the-type-of-the-value-being-assigned-to-variable   so I changed the "Parameter Size" to 50 to match the query.

Comment: Go variable pane and change the data type for this variable as system.object , it will work fine for you.

Comment: This breaks the script task. I think its expecting a string to be used in the XML file path when writing the results to a file. I also get this:    System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.  Which either means the root element is missing or there are many root elements.